# Get path of image from intent when using camera and putting EXTRA_OUPUT parameter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I'm currently creating a functionnality for the user to upload images to my server. He can either takes pictures with his camera or from his gallery. 
I'm using this code to take a picture with the camera :

```
// create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

tempFile = File.createTempFile(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), ".jpeg", ContextCompat.getExternalCacheDirs(a)[0]); 
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(tempFile)); 

// start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And then to manipulate the image I use onActivityResult as such :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // use tempFile to recreate bitmap and do some heavy-wooshy-wishy stuff
        ...
    }
}
```

It works totally fine but I'm confused with the `Intent data` parameter when using the camera. In this case it is null and to use the taken picture I need to re-create it from the path I gave to the ... intent.

What I find especially confusing is that if I don't put any EXTRA_OUTPUT parameter, then the `Intent data` isn't null and I can easily get the path of the picture with `data.getData()`.

BUT THEN I just get a thumbnail from the original picture.

Is there any way to get the original picture from the camera and the path from the intent ? I don't have any real use case, but let's say the `tempFile` field gets modified or destroyed when you're taking the picture. Then on onActivityResult you will not be able to use the just taken picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I find especially confusing is that if I don't put any EXTRA_OUTPUT parameter, then the Intent data isn't null and I can easily get the path of the picture with data.getData().

Not generally. [There is no requirement for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to provide you a path to anything](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE). Getting a thumbnail back via the `data` extra, if you do not provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, is the only "result" that you are supposed to get back in `onActivityResult()`.

> Is there any way to get the original picture from the camera and the path from the intent ?

No, because you never get the path from the `Intent`. It may be that a few camera apps leak this information. Not all will.

> but let's say the tempFile field gets modified or destroyed when you're taking the picture

It is your job to not make that sort of mistake. For example, make sure that you retain this value across configuration changes and short-lived process termination, via `onSavedInstanceState()`.